# Python Pandas соединение двух dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concat

Не так давно сижу над Pandas и конкретно три дня сижу над этой проблемой, просмотрел много интернета, пробовал соединять через merge,concat, менять типы данных в столбцах, использовать циклы для заполнения по ключу, но постоянно не получается.
Первая таблица- res - данные с пропуском дат
Вторая таблица- df3 - это по сути столбец с полным набор дат от минимальной до максимальной из таблицы res.

Задача подсоединить res (по столбцу Col1) к df3 (по столбцу Col00) чтобы получить в том числе строки с датой, но пустыми значениями в остальных столбцах- потому что в res нет строк с этими датами.

Прилагаю изображение с информацией о таблицах и результате:

[image: пример таблиц и результата]

Спасибо

Comment: Впредь данные и код должны быть в вопросе в воспроизводимом виде. Никаких скриншотов. Иначе вопросы будут закрыты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так, пишу навскидку, поскольку вы не предоставили примера данных, с которым можно было бы работать:

```
res.merge(df3, how='right', left_on='Col1', right_on='Col00')
```

Обратите внимание на тип джойна - `right`, это аналогично тому, как в `SQL` бы делалось в подобном случае.

И у вас ещё `Col1` типа `object`, возможно нужно будет его предварительно преобразовать в `datetime`:

```
res['Col1'] = pd.to_datetime(res['Col1'])
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот совет и этот вариант помог.  В моем варианте я пробовал что то вроде df3.merge(res., how='left', left_on='Col00', right_on='Col1'). Мою проблему скорее можно отнести к преобразованию типа, был невнимателен.

Comment: @Maxword Да, это должно было сработать. Видимо, проблема и правда была в разном типе колонок.

Comment: @Maxword, советую в будущем приводить [mcve] данных в вопросе в (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__). Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)